# Using CollapsingToolbarLayout setCollapseMode

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to set CollapseMode of the new CollapsingToolbarLayout

I can create new params for the child and can assign it. But this does not change the layout_scrollFlags I think i need to edit.

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(mCollapsing.getLayoutParams());
mParams.setCollapseMode(CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF);
mCollapsing.getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(mParams);
```

So I would like to turn on and off the scroll mode.

Has anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours of playing with this.

Turns out that the layout_scrollFlags is a layoutparams in AppBarLayout class.

You can get the current flags using

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) abBar.getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams();
int currentScrollFlags = mParams.getScrollFlags();
```

This means you can turn it off by using

```
 mParams.setScrollFlags(0);
```

Some may ask why, I need my user to make a selection in the view bellow, once this has happened i will turn the flag to 3, which is scroll|exitUntilCollapsed
You can also use

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS_COLLAPSED
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: how would i collapse it first then set scrollflags to 0.??